# Laravel - What's the benefit of calling query() method on an Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

In the course "Eloquent Performance Patterns" by Jonathan Reinink I've seen him calling `query()` method on his Eloquent models before writing the actual query. Let me give an example:

```php
User::query()
    ->with('company')
    ->paginate()
```

As far as I know, he could write:

```php
User::with('company')
    ->paginate()
```

I've seen this practice over and over in his course. It raised a question in my head: Is there any benefit in doing so or is it just a personal preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, you don't have to add `query()`. It was practical to instantiate the query for the cases similar to this;

```
$user = User::query();
        
if (true) { // check some condition and append query condition(s)
    $user->with('company');
}
        
return $user->paginate();
```

but then `when` method came and it became easier to do that;

```
return User::query()
    ->when(true, function (Builder $builder) {
        $builder->with('company');
    })
    ->paginate();
```

Comment: So, you think that it's only a personal preference?

Comment: I almost agree with you. There is indeed no functional difference (except for the cases you mentioned) but from the developer experience point of view there is autocompletion in for example PhpStorm which is actually correct when going from the `query()` method.

Comment: yes @TheSETJ it is just personal preference, i think people start to use and it become habit.

Comment: @AlexBouma I've been using for years both PhpStorm(Intellij Idea Ultimate) and Laravel but never used `query` but it auto-completes as it is seen in here https://prnt.sc/tdb1v4 (both ide-helper and laravel plugin enabled)

Comment: Nice explanation @Ersoy

Comment: @Ersoy With those plugins it is indeed not needed.